# Decode for json value?

Tags: php, json

I want foreach a row from database and get value it, but have error:

`$row->airline` is this: `[{"name_airline":"aaaaa"},{"name_airline":"bbbbb"},{"name_airline":"ccccc"}]`

```
foreach ($results->result() as $idx => $row) {
    $airline = json_decode($row->airline);
    foreach ($airline as $val) {
        echo '<td>' . $val . '</td>'; //Line 97
    }
}
```

Eror:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
>
> Filename: core/Loader.php(679) : eval()'d code
>
> Line Number: 97

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `echo '<td>' . $val->name_airline . '</td>'`